# R: how to add rows in dataframe by manipulating a datetime column

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, data-wrangling

I have a table of reference stock symbol that looked like this

[image]

I want to investigate the price change around each "showdate".

For exmaple, I want to add 2 new rows for one existing row, with a showdate -1 and + 1 day, essentially inflating the table 3 times. Leaving all other columns empty except making sure the symbol is added correctly.

```
That is: 
for first row             ZTS 2017-01-09 Buy 
I want to add 2 more rows ZTS 2017-01-08
                          ZTS 2017-01-10

For the next row          ZTS 2016-11-02 Buy 
add 2 more rows           ZTS 2016-11-01 
                          ZTS 2016-11-03 
etc...
```

I read about add_rows() but the function wont let me. and this post doesn't solve it either
[Add rows to a data-frame based on values in one of the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565492/add-rows-to-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-one-of-the-columns)

Can someone do this? Usually I deal only with columns.....

```
>dput(head(sanitised))
structure(list(Company = c("Agilent Technologies ", "Agilent 
Technologies ", 
"Agilent Technologies ", "Agilent Technologies ", "Agilent 
Technologies ", 
"Alcoa "), symbol = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "AA"), showdate = 
c("2021-08-18", 
"2020-04-16", "2017-11-17", "2017-03-23", "2016-05-13", "2016-10- 
07"
), call = c("Buy", "Buy", "Buy", "Buy", "Buy", "Buy"), 
show_segment = c("Guest Interview", 
"Guest Interview", "Discussed Stock", "Featured Stock", 
"Discussed Stock", 
"Discussed Stock"), call_price = c("$163.02", "$78.75", "$68.79", 
"$53.18", "$42.49", "$31.37"), current_returns = c("+0.0%", 
"+0.0%", 
"+0.0%", "+0.0%", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"), day_7_returns = c("", "", 
"", "+0.3%", "+5.7%", "-15.7%"), day_14_returns = c("", "", "", 
"-0.1%", "", ""), day_30_returns = c("", "", "", "", "+6.8%", 
"-19.7%")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `dput()` to provide reproducible data. A picture leaves out important information such as what kind of date object you have.

Comment: @dcarlson sorry about that. Here is it, I had a big trim on the table to show the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `split` and `map_dfr`. I've assumed that the values in most columns will be `NA` for the added rows. You could of course add other values in `add_row`.

```
library(tidyverse)

sanitised %>%
  mutate(showdate = as.Date(showdate, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
  split(list(sanitised$symbol, sanitised$showdate)) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x) {
    x %>%
      # any other columns you want to keep could go in here as well
      add_row(symbol = x$symbol, showdate = x$showdate - 1) %>%
      add_row(symbol = x$symbol, showdate = x$showdate + 1)
  })
```

Comment: Ho @Harrison Jones, thank you for the help, it is running on my laptop (sorry the actual table has 9000 rows, but it looks like it is working). May I ask if you can explain a little on the split and map_dtr bit? I'm too much a newbie still to this level. Like what they are doing?

Comment: Also, can I be greedy to ask you have a look on my other question please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396350/r-how-to-loop-read-csv-files-and-extract-information-within-each-file-by-matchi

Comment: `split` takes the data frame and converts it into a list. For answering your question it's just a way to organize the data. `map_dfr` will run a function on each list element, which in this case is every combination of the columns `symbol` and `showdate`.
One alternative that I was considering is using `group_modify`. Someone might provide a different answer using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach with a loop assuming "symbol" is the only column copied:

```
x$showdate <- as.Date(x$showdate)
for(i in rownames(x)){
    x[paste0(i, ".", 1), "showdate"] <- x[i, "showdate"] - 1
    x[paste0(i, ".", 2), "showdate"] <- x[i, "showdate"] + 1
    x[paste0(i, ".", 1), "symbol"] <- x[i, "symbol"]
    x[paste0(i, ".", 2), "symbol"] <- x[i, "symbol"]
}
x <- x[order(rownames(x)), ]
```